# How to solve Xamarin Forms API deprecated Error 410

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 shows this error when I'm trying to upload my apk:

`This API has been deprecated and is no longer available`

Any idea what cause and how to solve this error?

Xamarin 4.12.3

[image: Error 410]

Comment: Try with VS2019 ... I had many issues when trying to upload an APK with VS2017, even though now I deploy everything through AppCenter

Comment: Is there any more error details?

Comment: i posted some solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59172325/visual-studio-distribute-xamarin-android-app-error-this-api-has-been-deprecated, but for me they didn't work, maybe they work for you

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No more details.

Comment: Are you using old Google Play Developer API as Anthony mentioned in his answer? Also, an issue has been fired [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html). I will update you if I find anything.

Comment: No, I'm not using any API by Google, probably VS using an old Play Developer API. @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: OK, I will report it. You can also follow the issue in developercommunity to get the latest information.

Answer (score 2):

("Since I am answering as a guest it is not allowing me to embed images so there are image links below")

The issue happens in vs2019 also and I think it is being caused by this message in the Google Play Console

[ACTION REQUIRED: Your automated publishing to Google Play will stop working on December 1, 2019
Your app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available, and any calls to these versions will fail. Update to version 3 before this date. Learn more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51jeJ.png)

I am not sure how to fix this yet but if you need to get a release out you can manually grab the apk and upload it to the google play console.

Archive Manager > click on the desired apk > click open folder > grab apk file from the "signed-apks" folder

you can then go to the google play console and create a release and manually upload the apk file along with your newly created release.

I know this is not the fix I just figured I would through it out there in case it can help anyone.

[Same Error Message in 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui1KX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Same Message (VS 2019, 16.3.10; all Nuget-Packages updated, etc.)
I'm pretty sure it's the upload from within VS that is using an old API Call. Until now I didn't get a confirmation from MS Support - still waiting for it.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html

Comment: This support request is public? Can you share a link?

Comment: @tvdias https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft patched [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html) in the new version 16.4.2 of Visual Studio ([see patch notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.4.2)).

Please make sure to update to this version to fix the problem.