# Visual studio distribute Xamarin Android APP. Error This API has been deprecated and is no longer available. [410]

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I use visual studio 2019 to publish an Android app made with Xamarin.

To distribute the app I have always used the visual studio "Archive Manager".

I create the APK with the classic "Archive ..." command, then select the generated APK and click "Distribute ...", select Google play, the signature, the account, the "Alpha" channel and error:

> This API has been deprecated and is no longer available. [410]

What should I do to resolve?

I can publish manually, but this automatic system is very convenient.

thanks a lot.

P.S.

I already read this post https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6528
and the problem is VS2019.
Last version don't work. why?

similar situation here [What is "We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play developer API" warning in Google Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700332/what-is-we-ve-detected-that-your-app-is-using-an-old-version-of-the-google-play)
I have already tried to reconnect the project to a new API project but nothing

Any Idea?

All start when Google Play Store show this message:

> We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google
>   Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API
>   will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.
>   Learn more:
>   https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

Comment: Have you updated to the new API?Then you can try to delete bin and obj folders, then restart VS and try again.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is how do i upgrade the VS2019 API?

Comment: All component of my app are updated, and the APK manually distribute in the Google Play store work fine. I think that is a problem of VS2019

Comment: I just updated VS to last version (Version 16.4.0) but same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now, the only solution I've found, is to publish manually.

Archive Manager > click on the desired apk > Distribute.. > Ad Hoc > Sign and save to local drive.

Go Google play store > creare new release > add APK file

ticket open on VS Forum
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/844304/api-has-been-deprecated-410.html

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who have similar question wil get help from here? Thanks. :)

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't understand your request, my answer is already in answer section... what do you mean? do you mean accept the answer? ok

Answer (score 3):

A fix has been published in the [16.4.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.4.2) version of the Visual Studio.
Update your editor, and you will be able to publish like before.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try to Update Your Visual Studio Version